# Estimate $\sqrt{10}$ with an error smaller than $0.01$

Tags: calculus

I´m trying to find this using Lagrange Error bound.
$$|R|\leq \frac{f^{n+1}(t) (x-a)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$
Basically I thought of using the function $f(x) = \sqrt{x+1}$ centered on $a= 8$ (but when I was calculating the derivatives I couldn't find a "pattern")
So, I tried using $f(x) = \sqrt{x+1}$, $a= 0$ but in Langrage Error bound I need to work with the $n+1$ derivate and I couldn't find a pattern or how to work with it (I know that $(x-a)^{n+1}$ in this case is equal to $9^{n+1}$ and I have to try with differents "$n$" to know what order I need to work with). I'd appreciate some help to know how to deal with $f^{n+1}(t)$ (with t between $0$ and $9$ in this case). (I tried to find a general Taylor Polynomial but it has double factorial $!!$ and I get confused a little bit)

Comment: I know that I could try with differents n¨s for $f^{n+1}$ but I don´t think is the right way to do this kind of problem

Comment: If you want to approximate $\sqrt{1+x}$, then it's only useful when $|x|<1.$ So you should first do something like:
$$\sqrt{10} = 4\sqrt{\frac 58} = 4\sqrt{1 - \frac 38}=...$$
There might be better choices other than $4$. Actually, pulling out $3$ will work better I think.

Comment: What did you get for the various derivatives of $\sqrt{x+1}$? It may help to not multiply the coefficients when you bring them down to see the pattern.

Comment: Are you looking for a formula or a numerical method?

Comment: Thanks! I see the main Idea, it´s very helpful, I couldnt find how to establish a generic "n+1 derivate" for the polynomial of Taylor

Comment: @copper.hat I was looking for a numerical method but I though that maybe I needed a general formula to work with

Comment: You specifically need just two decimal places, so (1) you actually need to explicitly evaluate each term to get the answer and (2) you'll only need a certain number of terms to bound the error to $0.01$, and then you can stop. Technically you don't need a general formula.

Comment: What are you allowed to use?  I know that $\sqrt {10} \approx 3.162$, so I can just square that and estimate the error to show it is good enough.

Comment: @RossMillikan I'm allowed to use polynomials of Taylor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$\sqrt {10}=\sqrt{9+1}=\sqrt{9\left(1+\frac{1}{9}\right)}=3\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{9}}$$
Without using the binomial coefficient, you can express $\sqrt{1+x}$ as follows:
$$\sqrt{1+x}=1+\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k!}\frac{(2k-3)!!}{2^k}x^k $$

Comment: Thanks! I think that I can use that for what I need in the Langrage Error bound (I can calculate the n+1 derivate, and use x=1/9) and find the n

Comment: @Jean do you need a simpler solution or this is ok? You can express the formula with the binomial coefficient. Let me know :)

Comment: I think I understood, but just to be sure. To calculate te error (with Langrage error bound) I have to work with that formula (derivate it) and multiply it by 3?

Comment: @Jean Sure, that's correct :)

Answer (score 2):

It is not entirely clear what you are looking for.

If you apply Newton's method to $f(x) = x^2-10$ and start from some $x_0 > \sqrt{10}$, say $x_0 = 4$, then the sequence of iterates $x_{n+1} = {1 \over 2} (x_n+{10 \over x_n})$ decreases to the positive solution $x_n \downarrow \sqrt{10}$. The sequence converges quadratically since $f'(\sqrt{10}) \neq 0$.

Here is a crude formula to bound the error in terms of $f$. Note that the iterates satisfy $x_n \in [3,4]$,

Note that for $x \in [3,4]$, we have $f(x) = (x-\sqrt{10})(x+\sqrt{10}) \ge 6(x-\sqrt{10}) $ and so
$x-\sqrt{10} \le {1 \over 6} (x^2-10)$.

Starting with $x_0=4$, we get $x_1-\sqrt{10}\le 0.9375$, $x_2-\sqrt{10} \le 0.0012452...$, with $x_2 =3.163461...$.

(Not that it matters, but $x_3-\sqrt{10} \le 0.00000023351...$.)

Answer (score 1):

The [Taylor formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem) of order $n$ at point $a$, with Lagrange remainder, for the function  $f(x) = x^N$, ($N$ not necessarily a natural number) is

$$x^N = \sum_{\ell=0}^n \binom{N}{\ell} a^{N-\ell} (x-a)^{\ell} + \binom{N}{n+1} \xi^{N-n-1} (x-a)^{n+1}$$

where $\xi \in [a, x]$. So it looks  like the binomial formula ( we have $\binom{N}{\ell} = \frac{N(N-1) \cdots (N-\ell+1)}{\ell!}$, and the remainder term would look like the next one, except that instead of $x$ we have $\xi$ between $x$ and $x+a$).

Now consider $N=\frac{1}{2}$, $x=10$, $a=9$, $x-a=1$, so we estimate $(10)^{\frac{1}{2}}$. An approximation ( in excess)  with [error](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Series%5B%20%289.%2Bx%29%5E%281%2F2%29%2C%20%7Bx%2C%200%2C%204%7D%5D) $< |\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{2} 9^{\frac{1}{2}-2}| < 0.01$ is
$$\sqrt{10} \simeq 9^{\frac{1}{2}} + \frac{1}{2} 9^{\frac{1}{2}-1}\cdot 1 =3+\frac{1}{6}$$